# How to Solve NACLO problem on Old Persian Cuneiform?

Tags: historical-linguistics, computational-linguistics, ancient

Below is a problem from NACLO 2022 Open Round titled "Set in Stone". The language is Old Persian cuneiform.
[image: Cuneiform script words]

[image: Latin alphabet for Cuneiform language]

The goal is to match the translations.  The problem also states

> Note that one word can be written in two different ways in cuneiform!

The solution is above
[image: The Solution]

But I am very confused as to solve this problem, especially given the quote from the question. I was able to reason that since the problem says this language was written on clay tablets and came from Sumerian Empire, and since the Sumerian Empire was in Mesopotamia which is surrounded by the Tigris and Euphrates rivers, the clay tablets were likely wet during the writing. Thus, this language's directionality is probably left-to-right, because otherwise the writing would be smudged like when writing right-to-left with a pen. I was later able to verify this on the internet. But I couldn't match any of the translations.

Could someone please explain how to solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Old Persian cuneiform was inspired by Mesopotamian cuneiform, but it wasn't written on clay tablets: the Persians just saw "oh, huh, 'writing' means making little wedges" and made their own writing system out of little wedges even though they didn't have the medium that required it. This doesn't actually affect the problem, I just think it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that there's one word that's a subset of another word: *baga* is part of *Bagadāta*. So start by looking for one word that's entirely contained within another. This points to 21 and 13; since 21 is the leftmost part of 13, and *baga* is the first part of *Bagadāta*, that indicates the language is written from left to right.

We don't see the *baga* glyph anywhere else, so that's probably a logogram. But *dāta* is made up of three glyphs, and we see those first two glyphs in 6 and 12 as well. There are two other words that start with *dā* (*Dārayauš* and *dāruv*), so those two glyphs somehow mean *dā*.

Furthermore, *Dārayauš* and *dāruv* both have an *r* after the initial *dā*, but they don't have the same glyph there in cuneiform. So this is probably a syllabic writing system: *dā* is written as *da-a*, and the next glyph in those two words would be *ra* and *ru*. Indeed, we see one of those glyphs at the start of a different word (19), which could be *radīy*; there's no word in the list that starts with *ru*.

Now we have five words identified and know how the system generally works. From here you should be able to figure out the rest (for example, *da* on its own should appear in *daiva* and *āyadana*). As a hint, it's not *quite* a syllabary, but it's pretty close to one. Good luck!

Comment: Note: The first step in this analysis only works under the assumption that the script is unicameral. If it were bicameral, we would expect _baga_ and _Bagadāta_ to begin with different wedges.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet True! Or if it had determinatives, or if it used a logogram for _baga_ on its own but not as part of _Bagadāta_. If we couldn't find one word that was a subsequence of another in the first step, we'd have to try a different tack.